# Using an LC3 Simulator to count the number of 1's in a binary number

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, bitmask, lc3

I am trying to write a program for the LC3 simulator that will allow me to count the amount of 1's in a binary number stored somewhere else in memory. Here is what I have so far:

```
0011 0001 0000 0000   ; Start the data at memory location x3100
0110 1010 1111 0001   ; Hex number stored at x3000

0011 0000 0000 0000   ; Start the program at x3000
0101 001 001 1 00000  ; Clear R1 (Contain address of number)
0101 010 010 1 00000  ; Clear R2 (Counter for amount of 1's)
0001 011 011 1 00001  ; Load R3 with 1 (Number for 'and-ing' with number getting checked)
;^cant do this line since that is a decimal 1 not binary one therefore it wouldnt left shift
; and cant store and get a binary number in memory

0001 100 100 1 01111  ; Load R4 with 16 (Loop loops til 0)
1110 001 011111100    ; Load R1 with address of number
0110 101 001 000000   ; Load R5 with the number stored at x3100
0101 110 101 000 011  ; And R3 with R5 store result in R6
                      ; If number is not zero, increment R2 by 1
0001 011 011 000 011  ; Add R3 with itself to make a left shift
0001 100 100 1 11111  ; Decrement R4 by 1
                      ; Loop to x3006 (When R3 is 'And-ed' with R5) if R4 isnt 0
0011 010 011111101    ; Store value from R2 in x3101
1111 0000 00100101    ; Halt (Is this correct?) set breakpoint here
```

I am confused as how to make an "if statement" to check certain values as well as how to loop back to a certain point if a condition is not met. My thought process on how to actually count the amount of 1's was to AND the original binary number being checked with "0000000000000001" if the resulting value isn't 0 then add 1 to my "1's counter" and then left shift the 1 value to check the next value in the original number. I noted that I couldnt do a certain line since I believe I stored a decimal 1 in register 3 rather than a binary one and would'nt be able to left shift it. One of my restrictions is that I cant use any other places in memory than x3100 and x3101 to store the original number and to store the amount of 1's respectively.

I have heard that a bit mask would be very useful but I have searched high and low and cannot find out how to use one. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which count 1s stored in R6, which by default I filled with x7562. Use branch and labels to treat the subroutines. ##

```
.ORIG x3000 ;start point

;R6 is the the register of number stored
;R1 is the register for manipulation of the number stored
;R2 is the counter for number of 1s
;R3 is the bitmask
;R4 is the loopcounter
;R5 is the storage for AND operation

AND R1,R1,#0; Clean R1
AND R2,R2,#0; Clean R2
AND R3,R3,#0; Clean R3
AND R4,R4,#0; Clean R4
AND R5,R5,#0; Clean R5

ADD R3,R3,#1; Set the value of R3 to 1
ADD R4,R4,#15; Set the loop counter to 15

LD  R6,FILL_R6
ADD R1,R6,#0;

CHECK  AND  R5,R3,R1;
       BRz  #1;
       ADD  R2,R2,#1;
       ADD  R3,R3,R3; Left shift bitmask
       ADD  R4,R4,#-1
       BRzp CHECK

STI R2,STORE_x5000

FILL_R6     .FILL X756
STORE_x5000 .FILL x5000

.END
```